# Randomly create holes in mesh in "Shading" Tab

Tags: mesh, texturing, node-editor, displacement, bump

I'am currently trying to make a cookie in blender. Looking at a reference photo, I found that cookies have small holes. So, to recreate this texture, I used a "Noise Texture" Node, which I inverted. This works well, but there are way too many holes and the holes are stretched, so all in all it looks really bad. *(see picture down below)*. **How can I fix this? Or is there a better way to do it?** I also tried to use Displacement and searched for this question on this page, but I didn't find a solution.

Thank you very much!

[image]

Comment: Try using Object or Generated texture coordinates for your Noise Texture (I think object will probably work best to avoid the stretching). Also, add a ColorRamp after the Noise texture (before the Bump Node), so you can sharpen the Texture by tightening the sliders.

Comment: Thank you very much! I guess that answers the question, though I'm not finished yet.